# C programming - picking up the machine name, username at compile time

Tags: c, compilation

Are there a set of defines that are created at compile time, that I can use to populate a printk statement with information about where and who last build a kernel driver?  I know that there are predefined C macros, and I was hoping to find something in there that is dynamically set as the compile is kicked off, but there doesn't appear to be.

This would be specific to GCC as well.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could set them with a build script via the -D preprocessor option.

Comment: I'm assuming Linux - you may wish to add the [tag:linux-kernel] tag. You could do something similar to how the Linux kernel build creates the "include/generated/compile.h" file, which involves "init/Makefile" calling "scripts/mkcompile_h".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment; you could just use the shell function of make, in case you use make.

It could look something like this in the makefile:

```
USER=$(shell whoami)
HOST=$(shell hostname)

CXX=gcc
CXX_DEFINES=-D__BUILD_USER=\"$(USER)\" -D__BUILD_HOST=\"$(HOST)\"
CXX_FLAGS=-c -Wall -Wextra $(CXX_DEFINES)
CXX_LFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

EXEC=hostusertest

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXEC)

clean:
    rm $(OBJECTS)
    rm $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(CXX_LFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $<
```

Basically just use the standard shell commands to gather the information and create a variable in the makefile that keeps that info after using the shell function `$(shell ...)` to get it.

Then just set it via `-D NAME=VALUE` but don't forget to add escaped qoutation marks.